# SQLite Problems when using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am using SQLite and previous answers state that I should use this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfPerson;
    sqlite3 *personDB;
    NSString *dbPathString;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayOfPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];
    [self createOrOpenDB];
}

- (void)createOrOpenDB
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persons.db"];

    char *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString];
NSLog(@"here 0");
if (!success) {// THIS IS MY CONCERN
    const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"here 1");
    //creat db here
    NSLog(@"sqlite3 = %d",sqlite3_open(dbPath, &personDB));
    NSLog(@"OK= %d", SQLITE_OK);
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"here 2");
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, AGE INTEGER)";
        sqlite3_exec(personDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
        sqlite3_close(personDB);
    }
}
}
```

However, when I run this code my app does not gets into this loop:

```
if(!success) {
    ....
}
```

I tried using

```
if(success) {
     ....
}
```

and it works. But I do not think that is correct. Please help me.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at `BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString];` to check what is going on at that point, if it is not your favor, you need to breakpoint it earlier.

Comment: By the way, you're opening the database twice here! Once in your `NSLog` statement, and then again in the `if` statement. Make sure you call this only once. Also, the method name is misleading, as it's called `createOrOpenDB`, but it's only creating database if not there. But it's not opening database (aforementioned bug notwithstanding). But if `fileExistsAtPath` is returning `TRUE`, then that just means you already have a database there.